# Можно ли как-то реализовать закрытие сайта по кнопке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например я хочу сделать кнопку, которая автоматически закрывал бы мой сайт.Это реально вообще?

Comment: http://javascript.ru/window.close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так.
Но браузер затребует подтверждение закрытия.

```
<script>
    var closeSite = function() {
        window.close();
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="closeSite()">Выйти с сайта</a>
```